# log controller action time duration in ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net-core

For a requirement we need to log the duration for aspnet core action requests. At the end of the request the duration must be logged (stopwatch) and we also need to know which controller and which action method were used.

What is the best place to do this? Action filter, middleware? And how?

Answer (score 8):

ASP.NET Core already gathers this info. You just need to make sure it gets logged, in general, and where you want it to be. In development, these are sent to the console. If you watch that, you'll see logs like:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
    Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44301/
...
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
    Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing action MyApp.HomeController.Index (MyApp)
...
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
    Request finished in 7.981ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The main categories you're going to be interested in are `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`, which both log at level  `Information`. When running in production, the default log level is `Warning`, which is why you're not getting this logged there. You can simply add something to your `appsettings.Production.json` file like:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Information"
  }
}
```

Or you can specify logging to only a certain provider:

```
"Serilog": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Information"
  }
}
```

You can get really granular and complex with this. See the [docs on log filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-filtering) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to log elapsed time of the Controller/Action. You can write your own Middleware for this purpose. check the example below:

```
public class DiagnosticsMiddleware 
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DiagnosticsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
        _esClient = esClient;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    { 
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();


        await _next(context);

        sw.Stop();
        var elapsedTime = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
        LogContext.PushProperty("ElapsedTime", elapsedTime);
    }

}
```

and you can configure it like

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ContextEnricherMiddleware>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks and how do I know which controller and action is being invoked or was invoked during that request?

Comment: I am not with my sources yet. can you try  `var routeData = context.GetRouteData();`?