# Serilog Timestamp is at end of request when using UseSerilogRequestLogging, can I override this?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

NET Core app I am using Serilog with `UseSerilogRequestLogging()` and writing additional information to the log with `IDiagnosticContext`.

I have noticed the Timestamp of this log output will be when the event ends. Say my request starts at 1613516400 and takes 2 seconds, the log will list the timestamp as 1613516402.

Is there any way to make this Timestamp the start of the request, so 1613516400?

Comment: hi, hmm, not sure, perhaps add a middleware to log the start time or the elapsed time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673817/log-controller-action-time-duration-in-asp-net-core